# addEventListener automatically triggers and keep continuing

Tags: javascript

I am using a click addEventListener to execute a function. But it seems to automatically trigger when the page loads and keep on continuing to trigger. How can I make the function work only when the button is clicked?

I am looking for a pure javascript solution (no jquery)

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function (){
    loadMesh(vertics);
    console.log("triggered!! :(");
});
```

console:

`triggered!! :( 
 triggered!! :( 
 triggered!! :( 
 triggered!! :( 
 ....         .`

Comment: Your above code will run only when you `click` your button. There is some other code, please add your complete code. It seems like on `pageload` you are manually calling `click()` event of your `button`.

Comment: @randomSoul you nailed it! thank you. :)  Please add your answer - I'll mark as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code will only `run` when you `click` button with id `myBtn`.

It seems like you are manually calling your `click()` event attached to your `button` when the page loads. Remove the manual call.